# compile TFLite-script with cmake (CMakeLists) for GPU

Tags: c++, cmake, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to compile my c++ script using TFLite with GPU-delegate. It works when I use a Makefile to compile, but I have no iead how to do it in my CMakeLists.txt. How can I translate the notation to use GPU-delegate from my Makefile to my CMakeLists.txt?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(TFLite)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../tflite-dist/include/)

set(TIME TFLiteTimeit)
set(TIMEGPU TFLiteTimeitGPU)

add_executable(${TIME} tflite_timeit.cpp)
add_executable(${TIMEGPU} tflite_timeit_gpu.cpp)

add_library(tensorflowlite SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET tensorflowlite PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../tflite-dist/libs/linux_x64/libtensorflowlite.so)

target_link_libraries(${TIME} tensorflowlite ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(${TIMEGPU} tensorflowlite ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Makefile:

```
all: tflite_test tflite_test_gpu 

tflite_test: src/tflite_timeit.cpp src/Detector.h 
    g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -march=native src/tflite_timeit.cpp -ltensorflowlite -o TFLiteTimeit

tflite_test_gpu: src/tflite_timeit_gpu.cpp src/Detector.h 
    g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -march=native src/tflite_timeit_gpu.cpp -ltensorflowlite -ltensorflowlite_gpu_delegate -lGLESv2 -lEGL -o TFLiteTimeitGPU


clean:
    rm TFLiteTimeit TFLiteTimeitGPU || true
```

Comment: "How can I translate the notation to use GPU-delegate from my Makefile to my CMakeLists.txt?" - If you mean the `-ltensorflowlite_gpu_delegate` flag, then it is transferred into CMake in the same way as `-ltensorflowlite` flag, That is, you need to link with the library `tensorflowlite_gpu_delegate`.

Comment: Does it mean that I need to create a tensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so file also then and add the same commands (add_library, set_property and target_link_libraries) for the GPU delegate?